# What weapons do A-10 Warthogs typically carry?

Tags: military, missiles

What is the A-10 Warthog's typical operational load out? Seeing as it is built a tank buster, does it actually carry anti-tank weapons, and what situations would they be used e.g would they (A-10's) ever use an AGM or ASM on a tank?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 30 mm [GAU-8/A Avenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GAU-8_Avenger)  with over 1000 rounds is in itself a potent anti-tank weapon, which can fire depleted uranium rounds, among others. It carries a number of anti-armor weapons like the [AGM-65 Maverick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AGM-65_Maverick), [Hydra 70](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydra_70) rockets and cluster bombs in 11 external hardpoints with a maximum load of 7200 kgs.

The 'typical' operational layout of aircraft depends on the mission. For example, the image below shows one configuration.

[image: A10]

By U.S. Air Force photo by Master Sgt. Blake R. Borsic - http://www.af.mil/shared/media/photodb/photos/000217-F-0656B-004.jpg, Public Domain, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=505075

In the above picture, the aircraft can be seen carrying a ALQ-131 ECM pod under one wing and two AIM-9 Sidewinder air-to-air missiles under the other wing for self-defense, along with AGM-65 and bombs. If these are not required (for example, where there is little danger from anti-aircraft fire), they can be replaced with others or the aircraft is flown without one so as to increase range/time on target.

[image: A 10]

By U.S. Air Forces Central Public Affairs Photo by Master Sgt. William Greer - http://www.flickr.com/photos/dvids/5510306058, Public Domain, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=37832505

In this photo, we can see the aircraft carrying only precision munitions and targeting pods.

Comment: The A10 was designed around the GAU8/A cannon, but once the aircraft entered service it was realised that a stand off weapon was needed to give the aircraft a reasonable chance of survival in the face of the Soviet short range air defences. This led to emphasis on the use of the AGM65 Maverick missile, which over time was upgraded with an imaging infra-red sensor and other improvements to increase it's effectiveness in typical European weather conditions.

Answer (score 1):

It has a 30mm cannon with depleted uranium rounds.

Comment: It carries more than that.